# Is there an open-source implementation of an XPathNavigator for POCOs?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I would like to enable XPath navigation over my POCOs (i.e. "plain old CLR objects").  From a brief search, I have found several options:

1. Use [ObjectXPathNavigator .NET 1.0 implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950764.aspx).  However, since it was written against .NET 1.0, I have concerns about potential issues with generics (and whatever else that wasn't supported back then).
2. [Implementing my own XPathNavigator by extending the .NET XPathNavigator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188773.aspx).

The second option appears to be what I want.  However, I don't have the time to write my own -- especially since I expect that someone else has already implemented it and made it open source.  I just have a difficult time finding this elusive PocoXPathNavigator implementation!

Thanks.

Comment: So why don't you try `ObjectXPathNavigator`?

Comment: Today one would use LINQ for this use case.

Comment: @svick, I would probably try it before I embark on implementing my own.

Comment: @Daniel, could you elaborate?  Thanks.

Comment: @IgorPashchuk: What exactly do you want to know? There is a ton of info about LINQ on the net.

Comment: Igor, I'm in agreement with @DanielHilgarth, I'm unclear on what you want to do, since you've described more of what you want to use.

Comment: @Daniel, I was curious about how LINQ could be used to perform XPath queries.  LINQ and XPath are two distinct query methods.  LINQ is already implemented but XPath is not.  My goal is to support XPath navigation.  (BTW, I'm already using LINQ for other purposes).

Comment: after further thinking, starting with ObjectXPathNavigator is probably best for me (any necessary changes should be minor, so I can handle that).

Comment: @IgorPashchuk: I assumed you needed a way to query objects, without the need for a specific query method. That's why I proposed LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Daniel.  LINQ is the preferred query method, legacy support considerations aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach, it seems, is to use [ObjectXPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950764.aspx) (option 1) since it's open source.  I plan to extend it to support generics and whatever else I need.

Answer (score -1):

You can **serialize** your objects as **xml string into memory** and then use the standard XPathNavigator to search in it. There are also some **native XML database** systems which you may use to serialize your objects into.

The question is, **why** do you need an XPathNavigator to search in objects?
If you have a large objects graph you may consider using some kind of **graph db / nosql db**.

Comment: good question.  serializing my objects to xml strings is *exactly* what I want to avoid due to performance considerations.  xpath queries on .NET objects allows me to support legacy mappings that used in-memory XML documents and performed horribly

Comment: why -1? Even if it didn't the poster of the question, it wasn't wrong.